# Missing data after 2 logical partitions were merged automatically

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, macbook-pro, hard-drive-recovery

I have a Macbook Pro with a 1 TB HDD in it. Windows 7 runs via Bootcamp.
I've made 3 partitions.

- 1 for Mac (HFS, boot partition)
- 2 for Windows (NTFS, boot partition and data storage partition).

A series of events happened after which the storage drive was merged into Windows boot partition.
Occurrence of events:

- Woke up Windows and logged into it
- After logging in, the system went into irresponsive state and I had to force shutdown the machine
- Tried booting Windows but all I could see was a blank screen. Had to force shutdown a couple of times
- Booted into Mac
- Been a while since I logged into Mac. So I have updated the OS X Lion to latest version
  And then updated to Yosemite
- Then after playing for sometime in Mac, I gave another shot for windows and it came up
- I booted it in safe mode
- Ran `chkdsk` command. Said it found no issues
- Then rebooted in normal mode
- Alls good but the storage partition is merged with Windows boot partition and I cant see any data in there
- Apparently its the **Storage Partition** thats missing and I had lot of data in it

Anyone knows how to get data out of it or if I can restore the partitions to their old (pre-crash) state?

Comment: I don't think I can help with the solution, but normally when something happens on an HDD it's best to make sure you stop using it to avoid any rewrites, so, stop using it if you haven't. I'll also assume you don't have any images you could restore from?

Comment: Yeah, I've not used it much. No, I don't have any backup images. And thanks for the formatting.